# How to add numbers tied to different accounts from multiple sheets

Tags: excel

I was wondering how one would create a function that would search through all the sheets on a workbook and collect associated numbers from each sheet on one master sheet.

Example:

Worksheet1

```
Name        Amount
Dave        $20
```

Worksheet2

```
Name        Amount
Dave        $20
```

The function would search through the range of workbooks and when 'Dave' is detected, would select the associated value beside Dave in the amount column.

Thanks!

Comment: If you want it with formulas, you can use [`SUMIF`](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/SUMIF-function-169b8c99-c05c-4483-a712-1697a653039b?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US). If you want it through vba, a simple loop with an if and an accumulator variable will do the trick

Comment: Thanks for the response!Very new with excel, what would the actual function be within sumif for something like this?

Comment: Look at the link i provided. They even have an exemple that is almost identical to what you need (in the tips section) For the part that you need to sum several worksheets, you just need to call it a few time and add them togeter like `=SUMIF(...)+SUMIF(...)`

Comment: Thank you so much, that was literally exactly what I needed hahaha